# Google authorization in case of the domain change

Tags: oauth, google-api

I have built a service with user authorization via Google. My project is registered in Google APIs console and it has one `Client ID for web applications` which is strongly binded to my web domain.

Let imagine that in future I will decide to change my domain name. How would it affect users who are already registered? It seems that they would need to accept my application permissions again? What is the best way to deal with such kind of migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by

> strongly binded to my web domain.

Authentication is created using the `client id and client secret pair` in the `Client ID for web applications` The only thing that is specific to your domain is problem the Redirect URI. All the redirect URI does is tell the authentication server where to return the authentication to.

You could easily add a second redirect URI to another domain or another page on your domain.  You could also add a new one and delete the old one it wont mater users will still have access because the client id and client secret haven't changed.   So in the event you delete your current domain and create a new one just remember to change the Redirect URI to point to the new domain and the old authentication will still work.